# Are there APIs to enable/disable Bluetooth on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, windows-8.1

In Windows 8/8.1 it's now possible to enable/disable Bluetooth via the OS itself (see image below). This is awesome because it's device/driver-agnostic.

On Android, this is possible via [BluetoothAdapter.enable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29) and [BluetoothAdapter.disable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#disable%28%29), but I haven't been able to find anything to do this on Windows (even though it seems like it's definitely possible).

So I've tried using:

- [BluetoothEnableIncomingConnections()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - However, this only prevents new incoming connections. It doesn't disable existing ones.
- [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) - The problem with this method is that A. it is a non-redistributable binary B. it requires that you know he device ID ahead of time (so it's not device/driver-agnostic). Also, while it's not a dealbreaker, it'd be nice to *not* require elevation.
- **UI Automation** - Simply launching the PC Settings app and toggling the switch with keyboard events is easy, but it's super ugly, both in terms of proper coding practices and in terms of user experience. That being said, this is the only way I've found to achieve the behavior I'm looking for so far.

[image: Bluetooth Toggle Switch]

I'm writing a native Win32 app in C++, so I'm not constrained to any Windows Store app requirements, although, it would be great if there was an approach that didn't require elevation.

**TL;DR**

Are there any APIs, WMI interfaces, or anything else available to achieve functionally equivalent results to flipping the Bluetooth toggle switch? If not, are there any alternative methods which yield similar results?

Comment: _'How might one go about accomplishing this? And if it's not possible to be functionality equivalent to the toggle switch, are there any alternative methods which yield similar results?'_ What did you try, and where you've failed in particular. Just asking for working codes is OT, sorry! May be you get better results and more positive response, if you remove the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: the question doesn't ask for working code.  A brief description of the appropriate API function (if there is one) would be a perfectly reasonable answer.  And will close-voters please note that this is *not* a debugging question; if the "questions seeking debugging help" reason gets misused too much it'll get taken away from us. :-(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - That's the thing, I've searched and couldn't find anything, which is why I came here to see if anyone had any relevant knowledge they could share. I suppose I could have been more specific by asking"are there any Windows APIs that can do this today?" But I didn't start with that because I didn't want to exclude any options that didn't rely on APIs (e.g. a WMI interface or something of the sort).

Comment: Switch it off via the toggle in your screenshot; if you then go into device manager and see it marked as *disabled* you can use the `setupdi()` family of APIs to achieve the same result. If not, look for the corresponding wmi classes and see if they allow disabling.

Comment: Sadly, the radio management APIs [aren't public](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e790991c-d093-49b0-a0cc-d30755d45ce0/about-the-way-to-turn-onoff-the-airplane-on-windows8?forum=wdk); I don't know why, as the APIs are fairly nice.

Comment: @EricBrown How do you know they're nice? :) I wouldn't mind using an undocumented API if you know more about it.

Comment: Check where my blog sends you.

Comment: @EricBrown I checked out your blog and tried searching for Bluetooth with the fancy integrated Bing search but wasn't able to find anything. Anything specific I should look for?

Comment: The company name should be a clue as to why I might know about undocumented APIs.

Comment: @YasharBahman Same situation here. It's now the era of Windows 10, do you find the API to enable/disable Bluetooth?

Answer (score -1):

In win8.1 you should be able to call `BluetoothEnableRadio` to enable/disable the local radio.

Basically the manufacturers should include a method to accomplish this so  you don't have to load a dll.

"*Beginning with Windows 8.1 vendors are no longer required to implement radio on/off capability (for Bluetooth 4.0 radios) in a software DLL as described in this topic, because the operating system now handles this functionality. Windows 8.1 will ignore any such DLL, even if present.*"

check out this link which talks about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx